# How to setup twilio device in Angular app for the incoming call (i.e. API is in .NET 6)?

Tags: c#, angular, twilio, .net-6.0, twilio-api

I am facing one issue related to incoming calls,
so the situation is API is in .NET 6 and it's frontend is in Angular app and also it's multi-tenant application.

So the problem is I've created Twilio device in Angular app and also created incoming webhook on Twilio and webhook endpoint is in .NET API, webhook is trigger when incoming calls come but how can I connect incoming calls to the Twilio device which is in Angular.

I've also added incoming scope identity when generate the token for calls.

Note: Outgoing calls are working perfectly fine.

Expected Answer: What am I missing? Or Do you have any reference blogs or something, If so then please help tech community.

Thanks in advance.

Generating token in .NET 6 as below

```
var scopes = new HashSet<IScope> {
             { new IncomingClientScope(unique_user_name) },
             { new OutgoingClientScope(my_twiml_app_sid) }
           };
var capability = new ClientCapability(twilio_sid, twilio_token, expiration_time, scopes: scopes);
string voicetoken = capability.ToJwt();
```

And then setting up the device in Angular as below and with device ready function

```
device.setup(voice_token);

device.on('ready', () => {
      console.log('device is ready.');
});

device.on('error', (err) => {
      console.log('device is not ready. Error - ', err);
});

device.on('incoming', (call) => {
      console.log('incoming call', call);
});
```

Also created the incoming webhook with caller Id and 'to' number as below,

```
public TwiMLResult IncomingVoice()
{
    var response = new VoiceResponse();
    
    var dial = new Dial(callerId: my_callerId);
    
    // wrap the phone number or client name in the appropriate TwiML verb
    // by checking if the number given has only digits and format symbols
    if(Regex.IsMatch(to, "^[\\d\\+\\-\\(\\) ]+$"))
    {
        dial.Number(to);
    }
    else
    {
        dial.Client(to);
    }
    response.Append(dial);
    return TwiML(response);
}
```

Everything is working fine with above example but Twilio device is not triggering when incoming call comes.

Answer (score 0):

When you're `<Dial>`'ing a `<Client>`, Twilio will dial the client for you if that client is connected to Twilio using the Voice SDK. The `unique_user_name` you passed to `IncomingClientScope` is the ID of your client, and it has to match the content of the `<Client>` TwiML noun, so it should match the `to` variable.

When your client is connected by using your Angular App, the `'incoming'` event should be triggered and you need to accept the incoming call.

Based on the code you shared, I can't see anything wrong. It could be helpful to share how you get the `to` variable.

I'd recommend logging into the Twilio Console, clicking on Monitor > Logs > Calls, and inspecting your call and its TwiML. Maybe that contains some useful information.